# HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found -The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed while hosting application in IIS 7

Tags: iis, dotnetnuke

Getting this error while hosting DNN application in IIS 7.0 on windows web server 2008.
Tried using Application Pool's managed pipeline as Integrated and Classic both but no effect.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: These might help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677099/routing-http-error-404-0-0x80070002

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108704/asp-net-mvc-controller-causing-not-found-error-when-deployed-to-iis-7

Answer (score 0):

What resources are you having this problem finding? If static resources, make sure you have the STATIC files feature enabled in the IIS installation (add/remove windows features)