# ActionLink not working after publishing update from vs2010 to IIS 7 on Server 2008

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an existing ASP MVC3 web app running on our local web server which is a Server 2008 unit with IIS 7.  THe app is running great on the server.  I did an update to the app and tried to publish it from VS2010 Ultimate.  The app loads, and the new menu item is on the Home page, but when I click the menu button (which is an Html.ActionLink), I get my 'Page Not Found' page instead.  The site works great on my computer when run in debug mode.

I have seen a couple posts about having to alter the maproute in the global.asax, but the route I am using is exactly the same as the ones that are already there and working, except mine goes to a different controller.

THese are the menu links on the home page, the new one is the second (NewAPplicants):

```
<td>
    <span><%: Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")%></span>
</td>
<td>
    <span><%: Html.ActionLink("New Applicants", "Index", "NewApplicant") %></span>
</td>
<td>
    <span><%: Html.ActionLink("Volunteer Search", "DistrictStaff", "Home")%></span>
</td>
<td>
    <span><%: Html.ActionLink("Reports", "ReportList", "Home")%></span>
</td>
<td>
    <span><%: Html.ActionLink("Admin", "Index", "Admin") %></span>
</td>
```

and this is the maproute data in my global:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "_AppStart", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

    }
```

Your assistance would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Does that Action links render the right (supposed) url?

Comment: Yes.  This is the first time I have published from VS, but near as I can tell, all the files are there, but kind of hard to tell because it looks like many of the files are put into .dlls.

Comment: I would like to see html rendered by that action links and the whole message of the error. Maybe you have something wrong in your web config (e.g. forget to register UrlRoutingModule in httpModules)

Comment: The URL rendered is http://mywebserver/webapps/Eligibility/NewApplicant/Index but instead of going there, it goes straight to my internal "Page not found" located at http://mywebserver/webapps/eligibility/PageNotFound.htm?aspxerrorpath=/webapps/Eligibility/NewApplicant/Index

Comment: I suggest there is possibly something wrong in your web.config.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have seen around, it could be problem with configuration of your IIS.

- Make sure you are running your app in Integrated pipeline mode

Try suggestions in these posts:

- [ASP.Net MVC Controller causing Not Found error when deployed to IIS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108704/asp-net-mvc-controller-causing-not-found-error-when-deployed-to-iis-7?rq=1)
- http://blogs.dovetailsoftware.com/blogs/kmiller/archive/2008/10/07/deploying-an-aspnet-mvc-web-application-to-iis7